# Azure blob SAS and Localized file name

Tags: java, azure-storage, azure-blob-storage, jclouds

I am using jclouds APIs to upload files to azure blob but I could not find any way to generate SAS using jClouds APIs so using Azure APIs to create SAS for specific blob.
Problem I am facing is the file which i am trying to upload has localized characters in its name e.g. "Jérôme" which I have to encode and decode at specific level while uploading, I am making sure that at the time of SAS generation i am passing decoded(actual) name of file but I am not able to access the same using generated SAS.

PS. I have tried different combinations of encoding and decoding string(file name) in upload and SAS generation but all in vain.

Error I am getting is "No such blob exist" and in some case "signature validation failure"

can anyone guide me with appropriate approach for the same?

Please let me know in case code snippet is required.

**UPLOAD:**

```
try (BlobStoreContext context = ContextBuilder.newBuilder("azureblob")
                .credentials(this.storeName, this.storeKey)
                .buildView(BlobStoreContext.class)) {
            final BlobStore store = context.getBlobStore();

            payload.getContentMetadata().setContentLength(blobSize);

            final Blob blob = store.blobBuilder(URLEncoder.encode(blobName, StorageConstants.UNICODE_FORMAT)).payload(payload).build();
            logger.debug("Uploading...");
            store.putBlob(this.containerName, blob);
            logger.debug("Uploaded...");
            return true;
        } catch (IOException e) {
            logger.error("IOException while uploading file to azure blob", e);
            return false;
        } catch (Exception e) {
            logger.error("Exception while uploading file to azure blob", e);
            return false;
        }
```

**SAS Generation**

```
String url = "";
try 
{
    final CloudBlobContainer container = getUploadContainer();
    final CloudBlockBlob blob = container.getBlockBlobReference(blobName);

    url = blob.getUri() +"?"+ blob.generateSharedAccessSignature(getPolicy(), null);

} catch (StorageException e) {
    logger.error("Storage Exception was encounter in generateAttachmentSasUrl() :", e);
} catch (InvalidKeyException e) {
    logger.error("Invalid Key Exception was encountered in generateAttachmentSasUrl() :", e);
} catch (URISyntaxException e) {
    logger.error("Problems creating an URI was encounter in generateAttachmentSasUrl() : ", e);
}
```

Comment: Please provide a code example.

Comment: @AndrewGaul updated the same, as you can see I am using Azure APIs for SAS generation but jClouds for file upload

Comment: Can you provide a Fiddler trace of the upload/download?

Answer (score 0):

Please test with jclouds 2.0.0-SNAPSHOT.  Many issues with URL encoding were fixed as part of [JCLOUDS-217](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/JCLOUDS-217).